# yarn does not start in Jhipster generated project

Tags: jhipster, package.json, yarnpkg

My newly installed Jhipster project is runned but doesn't display anything  on the browser and when I type,'yarn start' at the project teminal

it threw the exceptions/errors as the following image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kguue.png)...

Comment: You have something using port 9060 already.

Comment: Don't link to external resources, please, provide all necessary info in your question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your error trace shows that you are trying to use port 9060 which is already in use by any other process.

Solution 1 : run your application on any other port.

Solution 2 : kill the other process which is running on 9060 currently.**

Solution 2 For linux please use following.

// to find process id of the process running on 9060

```
sudo netstat -anp | grep 9060
```

//to kill the process

```
sudo kill -9 <process id>
```